# 1 out of 1 hunk failed when applying path from Git Repo to Perforce Repo

Tags: git, perforce, patch

Could anyone point me is there anything I am doing wrong here and how to solve these kind of issues?

```
GIT version: git version 2.6.3.windows.1
Patch Version: Patch for Windows 2.5.9
```

T

Comment: Open your patch file and compare it to your repository structure and file content. Sometimes it can be a path issue (not applying the patch from the right directory level), sometimes it can be that patch does not find the line it wants to modify in the file because it has been changed.

Comment: Rejects are being saved at the right location. I guess the file path is good.

Comment: As @xavier-t said, the patch file is (generally) simple text that you can read. If you look at your patch file, you should be able to see what line numbers it is looking at in your file, and what data it expects to find there. Then, you can compare that to the actual data that you have in your source file, which may give you a clue about why the patch command detected the mismatch.

Comment: @user109260 : If you want more insight you will probably need to add the content of your patch file or part it , next to the content of the target file & path to your question.

Comment: Just an idea that occurred to me, are the files in the Perforce workspace writeable (i.e. checked-out) ?  By default if they are not checkout, they are read-only which could cause the issue ?

Comment: @XavierT. Yes, you hit the spot. They are read only. I will make them writable and post the result here.

Comment: @XavierT. Changing the status of the files in Perforce did not change anything. I am still getting these errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by using GIT to patch instead of using patch.exe (Patch for windows). I use the following command by changing the directory to the patch file and it worked fine.

```
git apply mypatch.patch
```

To ignore white spaces, you can also use the following command -

```
git apply --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitepsace --whilespace=nowarn mypatch.patch
```